# ioctl with SIOCIFDESTROY v/s close(fd) on tun0

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

Can you please tell me the difference b/w calling ioctl with SIOCIFDESTROY v/s close(fd)?

Does close() destroy the tun interface as well?

Answer (score 1):

A tun device is managed by the kernel. A SIOCIFDESTROY ioctl() removes the tun device.

close() closes the file descriptor you have in your user space application that's connected to the tun interface.

> Does close() destroy the tun interface as well?

No.

Comment: Thanks..to re-use the fd i have to call open again...? is open the only way to open it or Read/write API will also do?